# Using itemController property for items filtered using RSVP.hash

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

So I'm trying to figure out how to use itemController for items that I've filtered with regExp and then returning them as RSVP.hash.

I have a product model that has many stores. I'm filtering the data based on product name and store address & name. Since the models are related, I need to return them as a RSVP. This introduces a problem, that when I try to use itemController for those filtered items, they are not using the itemControllers property I've set up for them and do not return anything.

My code is below, how can I get the itemController to work, or should I re-write this logic in some better way?

**ProductController**

```
var ProductController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['application' , 'product'],
    itemController: "ProductItem",
    filteredProducts: [],
    ...
    actions: {
        changeCategory: function(category) {
            var productController = this.get('controllers.product');
            productController.set('productCategory', category);
            var shopSearchTerm = this.get('shopSearchTerm');
            var productSearchTerm = this.get('productSearchTerm');
            var regExp = new RegExp(productSearchTerm,'i');
            var shopRegExp = new RegExp(shopSearchTerm,'i');

            var promises = this.get('model').map(function(product){
                if(regExp.test(product.get('name')) && product.get('category') === productController.get('productCategory')) {
                    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                        product: product,
                        shops: product.get('shops').then(function(shops){
                            return shops.filter(function(shop){
                                if(shopRegExp.test(shop.get('name')) || shopRegExp.test(shop.get('address'))) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                };
                            });
                        })
                    })
                } else {
                    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                        product: [],
                        shops: []
                    })
                }
            });
            Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function (filteredProducts) {
                productController.set('filteredProducts', filteredProducts);
            });
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

**product-view.hbs**

```
<h2 class="product-price">{{ product.finalprice }} &euro;</h2> {{! as expected, with filtered data this is undefined }}
```

**ProductItemController**

```
var ProductItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    finalprice: function () {
        var rebateAmount = parseFloat(this.get('controllers.application').get('rebateAmount')).toFixed(2);
        return this.get('price') - rebateAmount;
    }.property('price', 'controllers.application.rebateAmount')
});

export default ProductItemController;
```

**product.hbs**

```
{{! looping through the filtered products, explicit itemController }}
{{#each filteredProducts itemController='product-item'}}
  {{#if product}}
    {{#if shops }}
      {{ log product.finalprice }} {{! undefined, this is "Object" not "Class" }}
      {{view 'product-box'}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
  ...
{{/each}}

...
{{! just looping through the model }}
{{#each}} 
  {{ log this.finalprice }} {{! correct value, this is "Class" not "Object" }}
  {{view 'product-box'}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be {{#each filteredProducts itemController='productItem'}} ???

Comment: Both work, so it is not that unfortunately.

Comment: Checking with Ember Inspector shows that the hash that is returned might be the culprit for it not working. The actual product is a value for key with the same name, and passing hash to the itemController does not work.

I need to figure out some other way to achieve this functionality.